# Does Axis2 provide any features for determining if a service is deployed or not?

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I've got a bunch of web services deployed in an Axis2 environment.

From my Java code, I want to find out if a particular web service is deployed or not.

I'm thinking, that one approach would be to try to grab the WSDL, if that is available, then I could assume that the web service is deployed, if its not, then obviously the .aar file is not deployed

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? Or does Axis2 provide any utlities that could achieve the same results?

Comment: Are you building a service or a client? Your Java code will run in the service, client or somewhere else?

Comment: This is development of a service. A particular service needs to check if the other services are deployed (by checking for their WSDLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a UDDI registry.  Something like [JUDDI](http://www.andreas-hess.info/programming/uddi/index.html)

A quick google search turns up: [this](http://www.andreas-hess.info/programming/uddi/index.html) -- which looks a bit old by probably still relevant.  Typically "discovery" of a webervice is done via querying a UDDI registry.

[1](http://www.andreas-hess.info/programming/uddi/index.html): http://juddi.apache.org/ JUDDI